# Oracle Weblogic EOL versions

Tags: oracle, weblogic, eol

This question should be technically answered by Oracle Support, but their response time is slow. Hence, I ask you is there a version guide that mentions which versions of Oracle Weblogic are EOL with their dates?

http://www.oracle.com/us/support/library/lifetime-support-middleware-069163.pdf here lists the information, but is confusing when it comes to precise information.

For example,

Oracle Application Grid Releases

### Release                        GA Date  Premier Support Ends Extended

Oracle WebLogic Server 10.3 *  Aug 2008 Jan 2014 Jan 2017

### Oracle Cloud Application Foundation 11gR1 Releases

Oracle WebLogic Server 11g R1(10.3.1 and higher)* Jun 2009-Nov 2009 Dec 2018 Dec 2021

Why does this have to be so confusing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That document seems relatively clear.

- WLS 10.3.0.x support expires 2014(premier), 2017(extended)
- WLS 10.3.1.x support expires 2018(premier), 2021(extended)
- WLS 12.1.x support expires 2017(premier), 2019(extended)
- WLS 12.2.x support expires 2020(premier) 2023(extended)

After extended support expires, you will have access to sustaining support, which is basically "you can search the support database and download fixes that we already made" and not much more.

Comment: Is WL going away completely, and if so - what is it getting replaced with?

Answer (score 0):

The document mentioned (http://www.oracle.com/us/support/library/lifetime-support-middleware-069163.pdf) is still the current document but has been updated several times since the original question.

Of note, the current end of support dates for WebLogic 12.2.* have now been moved back as follows:

- Premier Support - Aug 2022
- Extended Support - Aug 2025

But the heart of the original question was "Why does this have to be so confusing?" to which the sad answer is that Oracle make money from confusing their customers and tricking us into paying additional money for things like extended support. It is not in their interest to make it easy for us, their paying customers.